# 'Timestamp' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to multiply a pandas.core.series.Series (df1['col1']) with a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame (df2). Their indexes are the same but it always gives me back ' 'Timestamp' object is not iterable ' when I am trying to multiply them by doing

```
k = df1['col1'].mul(df2)


[In] df1:
[out]
Index         col1    col2
2065-12-20     12      apples
2061-10-31     12      candies
2045-11-28     70      marshmalow
2043-10-31     11      apples
2040-07-30     21      cars
2049-06-30     64      planes
2036-01-31     14      glasses



[In] df2: 
Index             col1    col2   etc.... 
2065-12-20         14      120
2061-10-31         18      800
2045-11-28         19      580
2043-10-31         21      12
2040-07-30         44      21
2049-06-30         1.2     17
2036-01-31         61.8    61
```

and I want

```
Index             col1        col2   etc.... 
2065-12-20         14*12      120*12
2061-10-31         18*12      800*12
2045-11-28         19*70      580*70
2043-10-31         21*11      12*11
2040-07-30         44*21      21*21
2049-06-30         1.2*64     17*64
2036-01-31         61.8*14    61*61
```

the df1['col1'] was in days before, I transformed it using

```
df1['col1'] = (df1['col1'].values / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
```

df1.dtypes = dtype('int32')

any ideas why it throw back an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception comes because you multiply with a whole DataFrame (including a timestamp column!), not just a single column:

```
df1['col1'].mul(df2)
```

Given the data frames you probably wanted:

```
df1['col1'].mul(df2['col1'])
```

---

If you want to process multiple columns at once:

```
df1['col1'].values[:, None] * df2[['col1', 'col2', ...]]  # explicitly list columns

df1['col1'].values[:, None] * df2[df2.columns[1:]]        # all columns except the first
```

Comment: thank you! I have a last question, when I try do divide I have Nan everywhere. Any explanations? There is a 0 in my col1 and I try to divide my whole df2 by it. Should  `df2[df2.columns[1:]].div(df1['col1'])` works?

Comment: `NaN` in every row or just in the row where the `0` is?

Comment: Everywhere.  .dtype is dtype('int32')

Comment: That's odd. I can't reproduce that. Could you ask a new question for that including a minimal sample case? It's hard to discuss this kind of issue in the comments.